# Linked contacts lost moving from WP7 to WP8

Tags: 8.0, contacts, people-hub, 7.x

I am moving from a Lumia 610 on WP7.8 to a shiny new Lumia 1020 on WP8.0. My live.com contacts are shown correctly once I signed in, but it didn't transfer my other accounts automatically - is there a way to do this, sync the phone state entirely?

More annoyingly, I spent ages going through all my contacts on the 610 linking email and FaceBook contacts properly and none of this is synced. Do I really have to do all this again from scratch?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Looks like the linking don't work properly after restoring.

Comment: I found it "just worked" for me, when moving from WP7.8 -> 8.0; just needed to add all the accounts back in for the new phone (don't remove the accounts from the old phone!)

Comment: I'm not even sure what you mean by "after restoring". The only option I've got is to enter my live.com account... it's not like I can restore using Zune because WP7 and WP8 use totally different software.

Comment: Visit `people.live.com`. Your contacts on there are what get's fetch to your phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get back all of them if you connect your facebook acount and your Live.com (Windows Live) acount back. 
You may go to Settings, and then to |Acounts and then add an acount. Then you have to add the same live ID that you've been using while on WP7. Then you connect via the Acounts tab your Facebook. Restart the phone and your contacts should be on the People Tile

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how exactly to do that?

Comment: It then ended up with duplicates. I unlinked and tried again and it mostly worked, with a couple of exceptions I found so far. I guess one downside of the neat hub functionality is that a 'contact' isn't defined in one place neatly

Comment: Consider adding this information to your answer. Information buried in comments can be hard to notice. For more information, see [How do I write a good answer?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Indrek It seems that you continue to **** me....